# Making button action on click on select2 js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i'm really looking for any kind of direction or help, in my code below, what kind of way i can do to make an action when the button ***"Add new item"*** is clicked.

```
$('#my_select').select2({
       placeholder: 'Name',
       tags : true,
         createTag: function (params) {
    return {
      id: params.term,
      text: params.term,
      newOption: true
    }
  },
   templateResult: function (data) {
    var $result = $("<span></span>");
    $result.text(data.text);
    if (data.newOption) {
      $result.append("<button class='add btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-10'> + Add New Item</button>")
    }
    return $result;
  },
    });
```

thank's.

Comment: Add a click event handler to it ... // Using _event delegation_ is probably a good idea, because then you won't have trouble "finding" the new button element, and don't need to resort to inline event handlers either.

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches here:

1. You can assign pass [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) attribute to the button directly
2. Pass an id to the button, and attach a [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#detecting_clicks) to the id using jQUery